# Problem when executing report ".jasper" in Apache ISIS

Tags: isis

The execution of the method "ReporteListadoVehiculos()" only displays up to the line "JasperPrint j = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, conectar());", and apparently there's an error that avoids continuing the execution.

How can I find the error that is avoiding the execution of the report, and which are the steps I should follow to fix this tipe of problems?

This is the code I'm using to execute the report:

```
package domainapp.modules.simple.dominio.reportes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

public class EjecutarReportes {

    public static Connection conectar() {
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/adet?user=adetuser&password=Passw0rd";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            if (con != null) {
                System.out.println("Conexion Satisfactoria");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return con;
    }

    public void ReporteListadoVehiculos(){

        try {
            File ruta = new File("C:\\Users\\4G\\Desktop\\Proyecto_Final\\Codigo\\AdeT\\module-simple\\src\\main\\java\\domainapp\\modules\\simple\\dominio\\reportes\\ListadoVehiculos.jasper");
            JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(ruta);

            JasperPrint j = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, conectar());
            JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(j,false);
            jv.setTitle("Listado de Vehiculos");
            jv.setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al mostrar el Reporte: "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK JOptionPane is part of swing. By default Apache Isis comes with a WicketViewer.
Try using a logger (eg. log4j) or even System.out.println() to get closer to the problem.